# Azure alerts outbound ips

Tags: azure, security, asp.net-core, azure-alerts

I have web application which is secured by firewall to allow only certain ips. But my app also need to process Azure alerts. Where can I find Azure alerts outbound ip addresses to whitelist them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a specific list for Azure alerts outbound IPs. As a workaround, you could try to whitelist the [Azure IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) with filtering by the region.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Alerts notifications are being sent by Action Groups.

For Action Groups webhook notifications, the list of IP addresses are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups#webhook)